# Where can I find detailed information on the votes that were tallied in the 2020 election?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election, data-sources

I need a comprehensive dataset showing when individual votes were cast and for whom across the USA in the 2020 general election. I can find totals on the county websites and presidential candidate totals by county, but what I need at a minimum is a dataset that includes the **timelines** of all updates from each precinct during the vote-counting process. That is, what were the actual numbers of votes for each candidate reported by each precinct, and when were they reported? I think it is likely that many journalistic sites had access to this info but I have not found it publicly available anywhere. (It should be made public.) If possible I need a dataset that includes anonymized voter IDs and the complete ballot contents, (including rejected ballots and why they were rejected, e.g., whether a signature match succeeded or failed), and very importantly, **their source** (mail-in, drop-off, or voted in person). Timestamped data would be greatly preferred, including if possible, the marked time of receipt and the time each ballot was tabulated.

The icing on the cake would be to find historic voter counts and ballot details (and if possible, correlated IDs) for past elections for comparison.

Anyone know of a public dataset I can obtain that fits any substantial part of this description?

Comment: This type of stuff is not available until long long after the election is over.

Comment: @MichaelMormon Then surely there would be data available for past elections? (Why would it be withheld until after the election results are finalized, by the way?)

Comment: Any reasons for the hasty downvotes?

Comment: This is a tall ask since all updates prior to the final tally are unofficial, and so any discrepancies are largely corrected on the next update and no effort is made to correct previous reports. So, while some counties might provide live updates on their websites, those are unofficial. And, due to transcription errors, local website data might occasionally differ from nationally reported Associated Press data. Ballot level info is not made publicly available, though I agree that that would be useful. Post election, minute by minute update information is not likely available for most precincts.

Comment: Since states and precincts both "do their own thing", it is especially difficult to get a consistent set of data for nationwide results. I think that the best you could hope for would be final counts by source (mail-in, provisional, in-person).

Comment: Most of the data you are asking simply does not exist ("the time each ballot was tabulated???") and the tone of the question is rather demanding ("I need" and other expressions) for such a high order of detail.

Comment: You seem to be asking for **individual votes** (BTW, Precincts, Counties, States do not vote, rather it is citizens who vote), so  think you are a bit confused when you ask for "individual votes"

Comment: @MichaelMormon what on earth are you talking about.. I'm looking at the 197*2656*4 row precinct tabulation of Georgia right now and I've plotted it and there are hilarious signs of fraud from all angles of statistical analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably no such database freely available, although as you noted some media organizations have gathered the updates... and e.g. 538 has produced timeline graphs [such as these](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/where-we-saw-red-and-blue-mirages-on-election-night/) based on those data sets.

[image]

I don't know if e.g. ABC and/or Edison Research charge for access to such data. Your best bet is probably to contact them and inquire on the conditions under which they'd make the raw data available to you.

In principle, anyone interested and determined enough could have created such a data set since the updates themselves were public information; it's just that they were overwritten on the state/county boards' websites etc. every time there was new data. (I've checked a few such sites and they only have the final tallies now.)

---

A different [q here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60083/what-happened-to-the-pennsylvania-presidential-vote-count-at-914-on-election-ni) actually provided the raw data that NYT pulled from Edison; it looks like the raw files are still available by state, e.g.

- https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/race-page/pennsylvania/president.json
- https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/race-page/michigan/president.json

Beware however that you don't get absolute vote counts except for the total; for each candidate you only get a (three digit) approximation of their vote share:

```
{"vote_shares":{"trumpd":0.593,"bidenj":0.384},"votes":958809,"eevp":17,"eevp_source":"edison","timestamp":"2020-11-04T02:11:23Z"},
{"vote_shares":{"trumpd":0.593,"bidenj":0.383},"votes":959682,"eevp":17,"eevp_source":"edison","timestamp":"2020-11-04T02:13:39Z"}
```

(Amusingly, this three-digit approximation is apparently a good part of [a conspiracy theory](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/did-a-drop-and-roll-phenomena-expose-that-the-2020-election-was-stolen).)

Additional searching finds [a github page](https://github.com/alex/nyt-2020-election-scraper) that pulled all this NYT in into one giant `results.json` file for all the states!

In the opposite direction, the NYT state data is actually obtained by them by "concatenating" precinct data (the state json files reference these)... and these precinct-level json files are also still available, e.g.

- https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/precincts/PAGeneralConcatenator-latest.json

They contain actual vote counts for candidates (not approximations), but these seem to be totals and don't seem to have any timestamps, e.g.

```
{"precinct_id":"Bethlehem 11th Ward 1st District","locality_name":"Lehigh","results":{"bidenj":410,"trumpd":218,"jorgensenj":10},"vote_type":"total","is_complete":null,"geo_id":"42077-BETHLEHEM 11","precinct_name":"","locality_fips":"42077","is_geographic":true,"votes":638,"is_reporting":true},
{"precinct_id":"Bethlehem 12th Ward 1st District","locality_name":"Lehigh","results":{"bidenj":439,"trumpd":169,"jorgensenj":12},"vote_type":"total","is_complete":null,"geo_id":"42077-BETHLEHEM 12-1","precinct_name":"","locality_fips":"42077","is_geographic":true,"votes":620,"is_reporting":true},
```

Further investigation indicates that there probably are separate files for each such update, named with the exact timestamp of the update, e.g.

- https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/precincts/PAGeneralConcatenator-2020-11-22T03:09:17.348Z.json

But the catch is that the state file misses the final portion of the timestamp (the decimal points after the seconds) in the update list it contains, so I don't know how to get all the precinct-level update files.

Answer (score -1):

I found that data you are looking for: https://pastebin.com/5xBeaQzh (PA 2020 election NYT .JSON extensions with timestamps, the links themselves provide all the identifying info needed). Further, here are the JSON files for GA 2020 Election (pastebin.com/CD05B8fw) and FL 2020 Election too (pastebin.com/ai9skssU).

Here's an example of the links provided in the identified paste bins. There are a lot of them.

https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/precincts/PAGeneralConcatenator-2020-11-04T07:21:12.617Z.json
https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/precincts/PAGeneralConcatenator-2020-11-04T07:37:18.545Z.json
https://static01.nyt.com/elections-assets/2020/data/api/2020-11-03/precincts/PAGeneralConcatenator-2020-11-04T07:43:45.178Z.json

Fizz's answer states *"Further investigation indicates that there probably are separate files for each such update, named with the exact timestamp of the update, e.g."* at the end of his answer and the links I provided lead to 100s of .JSON data sheets with precinct level time stamped vote tallies over the course of election week. I cant post them all here, its just too many.

I would like to add that is the data defamed Edward Solomon use to claim that the reported percentages for Trumps votes did not meet the natural laws of standard deviation and number distribution for naturally occurring numbers. Based on my credentials which involve critical risk assessment and root cause analysis for naval submarine systems, the math is irrefutable. If this data is accurate the implications are astronomical.

Comment: This looks like the same data linked to in Fizz's answer.

Comment: Well its obvious you didn't open up the data. These are all time stamped .JSON data pulls, the time stamp is in the link name! You can use Power BI to compile the data into a useable format as seem here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m7-ku181Ik&t=336s. Heres GA https://pastebin.com/CD05B8fw and FL too https://pastebin.com/ai9skssU. Downvote me all you want but whoever needs this, well here it is. Godspeed!

Comment: I did open up the data. The timestamped JSON data pulls are the same ones Fizz linked to in his answer. I didn't downvote your answer, but I did flag it as "very low quality", because link only answers are discouraged here. If that Pastebin file ever becomes unavailable, your entire answer will become useless.

Comment: You are actually incorrect, Fizz states "Further investigation indicates that there probably are separate files for each such update, named with the exact timestamp of the update, e.g." at the end of his answer and the links I provided lead to 100s of .JSON data sheets with precinct level time stamped vote tallies over the course of election week. I cant post them all here, its just too many. I highly suggest you revise your statement. As for the pastebin, dont worry those have been up since NOV 2020, and its all been backed up too.

Comment: Welcome to Politics! I've included the additional information from your latest comment into your answer. Without that information it's not really clear what was linked and it could easily be confused with similar JSON sheets mentioned by other answers. Further clarification what the different files represent (e.g. different days or places) would be a welcome addition, please edit that into your answer.